# Structure Packing using __attribute__((__packed__)) in GNU GCC

Tags: c, structure, padding, packing

We know that `_attribute__((__packed__))` means (most probably) "do not insert any padding to make things faster" and may also mean "do not insert any alignments to preserve alignment".

```
struct structure2
{
   int id1 __attribute__((__packed__));
   char name __attribute__((__packed__));
   int id2 __attribute__((__packed__));
   char c __attribute__((__packed__));
   float percentage __attribute__((__packed__));
};
struct structure2 b;
printf("   \n\nsize of structure2 in bytes : %d\n", sizeof(b));// output = 20
```

Why are all padding not removed(output = 14) ?

Comment: Please always [read the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bpacked_007d-type-attribute-3509) before using a vendor extension. It clearly says that the attribute may only be attached to struct, union and enum types.

Comment: You want the `struct` to be packed, not the single fields (which are already packed as they are scalar types).

Comment: I saw this type of structure from http://grok2.tripod.com/structure_packing.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) structure2
{  //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   int id1;
   char name;
   int id2;
   char c;
   float percentage;
};
```

It doesn't make sense to pack one single field. As you said it yourself, padding is about the *relationship* between fields, so the attribute belongs on the struct itself, not on its fields.

Comment: @dragosht, `struct __attribute__((__packed__)) structure2` , it's ok but output is still 20

Comment: @AnimeshKumarPaul: cannot reproduce, [works for me](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/7BDgXccSWkQQLwdJ).

Comment: @AnimeshKumarPaul What gcc version are you compiling with?

Comment: @dragosht, gcc version 4.7.1(tdm-1)

Comment: `__attribute__((packed))` may also be placed between the closing `}` and the `;`, thus:  `struct structure2 { ... } __attribute__((packed)) ;`

Comment: @AnimeshKumarPaul: Check on Wandbox, even in GCC 4.7.3 this works as expected.

Comment: @AnimeshKumarPaul: What platform is this for? Wandbox only runs on x86-64, and whether packing is available may well depend on the hardware. There may be architectures on which packed layouts cannot be implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug to me ...

By using your compiler ((tdm64-1) 4.7.1) and the appropriate `packed` attribute I'm getting the same behavior - see the `main` disassembly below:

```
0000000000401500 <main>:
  401500:       55                      push   %rbp
  401501:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  401504:       48 83 ec 40             sub    $0x40,%rsp
  401508:       e8 a3 11 00 00          callq  4026b0 <__main>
  40150d:       ba 14 00 00 00          mov    $0x14,%edx <-- your sizeof here
  401512:       48 8d 0d 07 7b 00 00    lea    0x7b07(%rip),%rcx        # 409020 <.rdata>
  401519:       e8 b2 60 00 00          callq  4075d0 <printf>
  40151e:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  401523:       48 83 c4 40             add    $0x40,%rsp
  401527:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  401528:       c3                      retq
  ...
```

Using `gcc (GCC) 4.9.3` in cygwin I get:

```
00000001004010e0 <main>:
   1004010e0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1004010e1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   1004010e4:   48 83 ec 30             sub    $0x30,%rsp
   1004010e8:   e8 33 00 00 00          callq  100401120 <__main>
   1004010ed:   ba 0e 00 00 00          mov    $0xe,%edx <-- your sizeof here
   1004010f2:   48 8d 0d 37 1f 00 00    lea    0x1f37(%rip),%rcx        # 100403030 <.rdata>
   1004010f9:   e8 32 00 00 00          callq  100401130 <printf>
   1004010fe:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
   100401103:   48 83 c4 30             add    $0x30,%rsp
   100401107:   5d                      pop    %rbp
   100401108:   c3                      retq
   ...
```

So, for some reason the compiler you're using seems the ignore the attribute. You may want to try a newer one, though - the newest version of this `TDM-GCC` seems to be 5.1.0.

Comment: Does the buggy compiler also support the OP's per-field syntax? Recent GCC does not (it doesn't allow the attribute on, say, a `char` field).

Comment: Yeah. I just saw that the OP was copying the code from an external document, so I was wondering if it was once supported by GCC. Never mind though.